# String cannot be cast to long

Tags: java, android

Ошибка

> java.lang.ClassCastExseption: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
> java.lang.Long
> long duration = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24);
> long endOfTask = System.currentTimeMillis() + duration;

```
long finalTime = save.getLong(APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER, endOfTask);
        long finalLong = finalTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer( finalLong, 1000) {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                String duration = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d : %02d : %02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l)), (l / 1000) % 60);
                chronometer.setText(duration);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(StartGame.this, EndGame.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }; timer.start();
```

Ругается на эту строку

> CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer( finalLong, 1000) {

Вот хоть убейте, при чём тут String я не понимаю, там же везде только long.
Помогите советом, пожалуйста.

P.S.: До этого было так:

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer( duration, 1000) {
```

и всё работало. Но это не то, что мне нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]!

Строка 144 это та, что я указал выше.

Весь код, удалил только кнопки:

```
public class StartGame extends AppCompatActivity {
long duration = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24);
long endOfTask = System.currentTimeMillis() + duration;
final String TAG = "STATE";
private long backPressedTime;
public static Toast backToast;
static SharedPreferences save;
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_TODO = "";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER = "";
Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_game);
    context = this;
    saveText();
    loadText();

 

    //Массив
    String[] tasks = {"..."};
    // Вычисляем, сколько слов в массиве
    int tasksLength = tasks.length;
    //Генерируем случайные числа
    int rand = (int) (Math.random() * tasksLength);

    //Ставим задачу
    String task = tasks[rand] + " ";
    TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
    todo.setText(task);


    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    Button buttonBack = findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);

    buttonBack.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartGame.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    });
    

  void saveText () {
      TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
      TextView chronometer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
      SharedPreferences save = StartGame.this.getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = save.edit();
      editor.putLong(APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER, endOfTask);
      editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_TODO, todo.getText().toString());
      editor.apply();
       }
        void loadText () {
        TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
        TextView chronometer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        SharedPreferences save = StartGame.this.getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
        todo.setText(save.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_TODO, todo.getText().toString()));
         long finalTime = save.getLong(APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER, endOfTask);
        long finalLong = finalTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer( finalLong, 1000) {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                String duration = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d : %02d : %02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l)), (l / 1000) % 60);
                chronometer.setText(duration);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(StartGame.this, EndGame.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }; timer.start();
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveText();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    saveText();
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadText();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    saveText();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}
```

Comment: по моему вы привели не тот кусок кода. приведите пожалуйста тот код, где у вас находятся эти строки которые ему не нравятся

Comment: добавил скриншоты, код

Comment: Вам нужно сделать разные ключи для SharedPreferences, например, public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "1"; public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_TODO = "2" и т.д.

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!